# Drupal 6, FAPI form submitted twice, why?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-fapi

using  this code:

```
drupal_set_message('form id: ' .$form_id. ' send with '. $delta . ' and field: '. $field);
```

I notice that every time I click the £send" button, the form is submitted twice, so I see something like this:

> form id: formname2 send with 3 and
>   field xxx form id: formname2 send with
>   4 and field xxx

the $delta, that one which change, is the delta of a cck multigroup field (i'm inserting a new field into a cck content). Here's the submit function:

```
function IngredientsForm_submit($form, &$form_state){
    global $user;
    $ls_id = $user->ls_id;
    $current_ls = node_load($ls_id);    
    $delta = $form_state['values']['delta'];
    $field = $form_state['values']['field_name'];
    $form_id = $form_state['values']['form_id'];
    $current_ls->field_descrizione_ingrediente[$delta]['value'] = $field;
    drupal_set_message('form id: ' .$form_id. ' send with delta: '. $delta . ' and field: '. $field);
    node_save($current_ls);             
}
```

Strange, thing only the first submission seems to be saved in the database, so the saved data is correct...

Any idea why there is a double submition?

Answer (score 1):

I would examine the form variable and see if the submit function is listed more than once. This might be in $form['#submit'] or $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'] depending on if this is a custom form or a default node form.

It appears the submit function is being called twice but the node_save is doing an update rather than an insert so the database appears correct.

If you do not see a duplicate submit handler being called, then perhaps post your code that builds/alters the form.

Comment: It hink you're right. I've got this two definitions:

`$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  
 );`

and 
`$form['#submit'] = array(
  'IngredientsForm_submit',
  );`

how can I merge them?

Comment: It does not appear out of the ordinary as far as your submit handlers are concerned. The first is the actual submit button, the second is the function that will be called when the button is clicked (assuming all validation passes). If you post your actual form function I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same type of problem, I think it is the way drupal processes forms. If you move the following line

```
drupal_set_message('form id: ' .$form_id. ' send with delta: '. $delta . ' and field: '. $field);"
```

into your submit function after you have saved your data, you will find that the message will only show up once.